# HashByte & comparing strings

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, hash

We are currently running a script to dump Active Directory user information into a database.

When we do the insert, we hash all the values into a hashcode column of type Varbinary(8000).  This column is used to compare the hashes on the next run so that we only update the records that have changed.
At the moment, when the compare is done, it always comes back as different.

I've reduce the script to a basic example and still get the same issue.
(Enterprise person is the local table in my database where we keep our people information)

```
SELECT 
    SamAccountName
INTO
    #TmpEnterprisePerson    
FROM OPENQUERY(ADSI, 'SELECT SamAccountName
              FROM ''LDAP://MyLdapDirectory''
              WHERE SamAccountName = ''myAccount''')

    select HashBytes('MD5',COALESCE(EP.SamAccountName, '') ) as originalHash
        , HashBytes('MD5',COALESCE(T.SamAccountName, '')) as NewHash
        , EP.SamAccountName as originalName
        , T.SamAccountName as newName
        , '"' + EP.SamAccountName + '"' as originalName2
        , '"' + T.SamAccountName + '"' as newName2
        , CAST(COALESCE(EP.SamAccountName, '') AS VARbinary(max)) as oriBinaryName
        , CAST(COALESCE(T.SamAccountName, '') AS VARbinary(max)) as newBinaryName
        , len(ep.samaccountName) as originallength
        , len(T.samaccountName) as newLength
    FROM
        [dbo].[EnterprisePerson] AS EP
        INNER JOIN #TmpEnterprisePerson T ON T.SamAccountName = EP.SamAccountName
where ep.SamAccountName= 'myAccount'


drop table #TmpEnterprisePerson
```

The result is the following

```
OriginalHash = 0xEB4A732C6372E7F1558D4C95E34CE6FF
NewHash      = 0x82DDB9733D5A7532D1C2C734807BE756
OriginalName = MyAccount
NewName      = MyAccount //Same as originalName
OriginalNam2 = "MyAccount"
NewName2     = "MyAccount" //Same as originalName2
oriBinaryName= 0x4C415245415541
newBinaryName= 0x4C00410052004500410055004100
OriginalLen  = 7
NewLength    = 7
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong when comparing the hashes or why they are coming out differently

Comment: add `CAST(EP.SamAccountName as VARBINARY(max)` and `CAST(T.SamAccountName as VARBINARY(max)`

Comment: I'm not sure what you want me to do with the casting.  If I cast the string before hashing it, I get the same results.

Comment: add the cast and compare the outputs of the cast. I want to see if the the strings have differences in encoding (eg. Ascii vs. Unicode).

Comment: Ahh good point.  I didn't think of that.  I've updated the question with the results.  The results are different.

Comment: newBinaryNAme is Unicode. ie. is a `varchar` vs. `nvarchar` issue, note how they map: `\4c` ->`\u4c00`, `\41`->`\u4100`. You need to store your local column as Unicode too, ie. change the column type to nvarchar. Don't try to cast, you'll get burned.

Comment: I guess when I did the insert into the temporary table it put it in as a nvarchar.  Great catch.

Comment: I agree with @RemusRusanu - better to store the original type than to use cast/convert. My answer was only posted to expose the datatype problem.

Comment: Remus if you want to post your comment as an answer.  I'll give you the official answer. (I did upvote your answer Chris as it could have easily been the answer as well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have a datatype issue.  Convert `T.SamAccountName` to varchar(N) - same type as what is stored in the database (or cast, if you prefer that over convert).

```
SELECT 
    SamAccountName
INTO
    #TmpEnterprisePerson    
FROM OPENQUERY(ADSI, 'SELECT SamAccountName
              FROM ''LDAP://MyLdapDirectory''
              WHERE SamAccountName = ''myAccount''')

    select HashBytes('MD5',COALESCE(EP.SamAccountName, '') ) as originalHash
        , HashBytes('MD5', convert(varchar(50), COALESCE(T.SamAccountName), ''))) as NewHash
        , EP.SamAccountName as originalName
        , T.SamAccountName as newName
        , len(ep.samaccountName) as originallength
        , len(T.samaccountName) as newLength
    FROM
        [dbo].[EnterprisePerson] AS EP
        INNER JOIN #TmpEnterprisePerson T ON T.SamAccountName = EP.SamAccountName
where ep.SamAccountName= 'myAccount'


drop table #TmpEnterprisePerson
```

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for the response.  I tried the rtrim idea but I get the same results >_<.  SamAccountName in my table is a varchar (fyi)

Comment: Can you get me the result of `, '"' + EP.SamAccountName + '"' as originalName
        , '"' + T.SamAccountName + '"' as newName`

Comment: I've update the question with your request but you'll see that the answer is the same in both cases.  I also tried ltrim just in case but that gives the same response as well.

Comment: Updated answer - could be a datatype issue.

Comment: I changed the SamAccountName in the insert into to a varchar(100) and the hashes now come back the same.